# RJS Conditionals based on Element Style - Ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, css, ruby, rjs

I have some RJS in a rails app.  I'd like to be able to check the style of an html element before executing an action on that element.
I have tried the following

> page << "if ($('current_thread_partial').style.display != 'none'){"

```
                    puts "HAPPY"

                page << "}else{"

                    puts "SAD"

                page << "}"
```

But the conditional does not execute.  In the example here both HAPPY and SAD are printed to console regardless of the whether display is none or not.  Any suggestions or another approach?

Cheers,

Slotishtype

Comment: Are you dead-set on using RJS? Is JQuery an option?

Comment: Yep.  That's why I'm a little confused.  I just realized that I am trying to control server side code with a client side conditional...pretty stupid.  Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make this code working just do:

```
page <<JS
if ($('current_thread_partial').style.display != 'none'){
  alert('HAPPY');
}else{
  alert('SAD');
}
JS
```

This code writes all JavaScript into page variable so it'd be executed by browser.

Your `puts` between `page << ""` sentences executes on server side and simple had not been sent to user.